# Are women more attracted to "bad guys"?

Tags: psychology

[Definition:](http://powertochange.com/experience/sex-love/datingbadboys/) A bad boy is a man who seems outwardly attractive, but is unwilling to offer sacrificial love in a relationship. He is too immature and preoccupied with himself to share genuine compassion, concern, or acceptance. A bad boy lacks character and might exhibit the following behavior: lying, aloofness, irresponsible dreaming, fear of commitment, sexual promiscuity, addiction to substances or pornography, selfishness, hunger for power, disinterest in surrendering to God, etc.

Elie Daily wrote wrote a whole [article](http://elitedaily.com/women/every-girl-secretly-loves-tucker-max/) **Women Love Bad Boys** and explained the reason why women are more attracted to bad boys.

Are there any experiemental or scientific studies that show that girls are more attracted to bad boys ?

Comment: In its current state, this question isn't very well defined. What constitutes a 'bad guy'?

Comment: @dwjohnston https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHngTC6KRnY&feature=youtu.be&t=1m27s

Comment: There is probably a good question in here somewhere, but it will need some definitions.

Comment: IMO, that definition made the question worse. I don't think that maps well to the community understanding of "bad guy", and "wrong guy" is even more poorly defined. I'm putting the question on hold until we can decide what the question is.

Comment: @georgechalhoub , I think this is a good definition. I will add it to the question

Comment: @georgechalhoub , Thank you very much, I find your edits great! it captured what was in my mind :)

Comment: The article doesn't claim what this question says it does.

Comment: [This answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/5230/19407) has a better(imo) definition, and it answers this question as a bonus.

Comment: Would make perfect sense. Men that willing to sacrifice his single status and freedom and potentially huge alimony are losers. Why would women want that?